# ImageMagick with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, build, imagemagick, rmagick

First thanks a lot for reading my thread.

I am trying to use **ImageMagick** with **VS2012** on **Windows 7 64-bit** for image rotation. Here is what I did:

1. Download [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-windows-installation.php) for windows, and unzip it.
2. Go to \ImageMagick-6.8.8\VisualMagick\configure\ folder, open configure.dsw in VS2012, and build it. It was successful.
3. open configure.exe in \ImageMagick-6.8.8\VisualMagick\configure\, and click "next" -> "finish" with default settings.
4. After step 3, an VisualDynamicMT.sln is generated in \ImageMagick-6.8.8\VisualMagick. I opened it, and set it to x64 release, then I clicked "rebuild".

Some of the projects were built successfully, but many failed (total some 30 projects, and about 2/3 projects failed building)

----------There are many weird errors, such as:-------------

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bzlib.h': No such file or directory

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory

......

Then I searched, for example, 'cairo.h' in the downloaded \ImageMagick-6.8.8\ folder, it is not even in there!!! This is very frustrating. The package is not coming with everything it needs? Now I am not even sure can I use ImageMagick with VS2012?

Anyone has any experience with this topic? How to build ImageMagick with VS2012? I am totally lost. Thanks a million up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** build **ImageMagick** in **64-bit** with **VS2012**.

Just follow the following steps:

1. Download ImageMagick-windows.zip from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/windows. This file contains the latest source code.
2. Open configure.exe in \ImageMagick-6.X.X\VisualMagick\configure. If you want to build a 64 bit version of ImageMagick make sure you check "Build 64-bit distribution" in the "Build options". Click "next" -> "next" -> "finish".
3. After step 3, an VisualDynamicMT.sln is generated in \ImageMagick-6.X.X\VisualMagick. Execute the file "UpgradeToVS2012.cmd" (requires Powershell) to upgrade your solution to VS2012. You can also just open the file VisualDynamicMT.sln without running "UpgradeToVS2012.cmd".
    **Edit:** *With the latest version of ImageMagick this step is no longer required.*
4. After opening the solution make sure you change the platform in the dropdown to x64 if you checked "Build 64-bit distribution" in step 2. You are now ready to build ImageMagick.