# Building ImageMagick for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, linker, imagemagick

I'm trying to build ImageMagick for Visual Studio Express 2013.
I've followed the steps here with the exception of running "UpgradeToVS2012.cmd":
[ImageMagick with VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419756/imagemagick-with-vs2012/22424330#22424330)

When I build it I get 4000 odd linker errors as presumably the libraries it uses aren't meant for VS2013. It works fine for VS2012.

Has anyone had any success in getting it to work with VS2013?

Comment: Have you tried running UpgradeToVS2012.cmd and then opening the .sln file with VS2013?

Comment: Doing it that way I get different errors about not being able to find header files, mostly afxwin.h

Answer (score 0):

Using @dlemstra 's advice I ran UpgradeToVS2012.cmd and opened it with VS Express 2013. This gave new errors about missing header files.

I managed to finally build the solution by using VS Ultimate instead of Express. I'm not sure why this worked but it did.