# How to use the ImageMagick API to compare images in C++?

Tags: c++, magick++

How to do the equivalent of the command line

```
compare bag_frame1.gif bag_frame2.gif  compare.gif
```

in C++ using the Magick++ APIs? I want to compare or find similarity of two images of same dimensions in C++ code rather using the command line.

Any sample code snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a compare function in the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive `Magick::Image.compare` is the method your looking for. There are three methods signatures available for your application.

- **Bool** to evaluate if there's a difference.
- **Double** distortion amount based on metric.
- **Image** resulting difference as a new highlight image.

For example...

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);

    Magick::Geometry canvas(150, 150);
    Magick::Color white("white");

    Magick::Image first(canvas, white);
    first.read("PATTERN:FISHSCALES");
    Magick::Image second(canvas, white);
    second.read("PATTERN:GRAY70");

    // Bool to evaluate if there's a difference.
    bool isIdentical = first.compare(second);

    // Double distortion amount based on metric.
    double metricDistortion = first.compare(second, Magick::AbsoluteErrorMetric);

    // Image resulting difference as a new highlight image.
    double distortion = 0.0;
    Magick::Image result = first.compare(second, Magick::AbsoluteErrorMetric, &distortion);

    return 0;
}
```

The third example would be the method needed to satisfy the command line

> ```
> compare bag_frame1.gif bag_frame2.gif  compare.gif
> ```

Comment: Perfect explanation. But i am getting multiple linking error while building solution. here is an example of same.                                                     > _1>Example_ImageCompare.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Magick::InitializeMagick(char const *)" (__imp_?InitializeMagick@Magick@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main_

Comment: Looks like a linking error. Better updated the project configuration to include libraries

Comment: Yeah updated the project configuration and it build successfully. (My solution set up: **Solution configuration: Debug**, **Solution platform: x64**) But it is throwing exception while debugging this line _first.read("PATTERN:FISHSCALES");_   here is what exception prints _Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD2FA06D in Example_ImageCompare.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Magick::ErrorBlob at memory location 0x00000000002AEF90._

Comment: `@emcconville` Can you please explain what are these code snippet :      _Magick::Image first(canvas, white);_
_first.read("PATTERN:FISHSCALES");_
_Magick::Image second(canvas, white);_
_second.read("PATTERN:GRAY70");_

Comment: Those are `Magick::Image` [constructors](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/Magick%2B%2B/lib/Magick%2B%2B/Image.h#L78). The `Magick::Image.read` methods are loading [pre-defined image patterns that ship with IM](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#builtin-images).  I would guess you've linked Magick++ library, but not MagickCore.

Comment: Code snippet:                                                                              `#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

**#include <Magick++.h>**

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Magick::InitializeMagick(argv[0]);

    Magick::Geometry canvas(150, 150);
    Magick::Color white("white");


    Magick::Image first(canvas, white);
    first.read("PATTERN:FISHSCALES");
    Magick::Image second(canvas, white);
    second.read("PATTERN:GRAY70");`
Its magick++ library only.

Comment: `@emcconville` Can you please help me identify the correct library files and header files to include. This is the link [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419756/imagemagick-with-vs2012 ] i followed to do initial set up and then i tried your above example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25191

Images are store in the [Image class](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/Image++.php) which has a `compare` member function. The [first link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25191) has an example on how to use it, and the Image documentation has a nice example on how to use `Image`.